# Bash - File content

Tags: bash, file, variables, syntax

I am trying to store content of multiple files to variable, but can't find the proper way. Example follows - I need to rewrite last line somehow as $content is not a file.

```
content="";
if (($# > 0)); then #input files given as arguments 
    for i ; do
    if [ -r "${i}" ]; then
cat "${i}" >> "$content" #I need to append contents to existing variable
```

Comment: Why don't you `cat` all the files in the variable content? `content=$(cat "$@" 2>/dev/null)`. Or if `content` is not empty to begin with, `content+=$(cat "$@" 2>/dev/null)`. This last one gives you a hint for the solution to the specific problem you're addressing: `content+=$(cat "$i")`

Comment: Instead of _saying_ thank you, please consider upvoting and accepting the answer that helped you `;)`.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a loop; the purpose of `cat` is to catenate multiple files.

```
content=$(cat "$@")
```

If you do want a loop for some reason, the conditional is superfluous; a loop over zero elements will execute zero times.

```
content=$(for i; do
    test -r "$i" && cat "$i"
done)
```

In Bash, you can append to a variable with `+=`; more portably, you can do `var="${var}newvalue"`.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that all the input files must be readable.

Comment: If they arent, there will be an error message. If you want to suppress that, you can redirect standard error.

Comment: @ondrousn: if the files are not readable (or don't exist, or are directories), `cat` will complain on stdout (that's why I added `2>/dev/null`) in the comment I wrote to the OP.